# String in struct is always the same

Tags: c

I have this struct:

```
struct match {
    int round;
    int day, month, year;
    int hour, minutes;
    char *home_team;
    char *visitor_team;
    int home_score;
    int visitor_score;
    int number_of_spectators;
};
```

And i have this function that loads in som values from a file.

`struct match matches[198];`

`int get_matches_from_file(struct match *matches)`

And i set the values with this in a for loop:

```
int year, month, day, hour, minute;
int m_round;
int home_score, visitor_score;
char home[3], visitor[3];
int spectators;

sscanf(line[i], "%d %d.%d.%d kl.%d.%d %s - %s %d - %d %d", &m_round, &day, &month, &year, &hour, &minute, home, visitor, &home_score, &visitor_score, &spectators);

matches[i].round = m_round;
matches[i].day = day;
matches[i].month = month;
matches[i].year = year;
matches[i].hour = hour;
matches[i].minutes = minute;
matches[i].home_team = home;
matches[i].visitor_team = visitor;
matches[i].home_score = home_score;
matches[i].visitor_score = visitor_score;
matches[i].number_of_spectators = spectators;
```

But when i print out the structs. All `home_team` and `visitor_team` strings are the same as the last ones in the file i load in. As if they were all changed in the end of the loop.

This is an example of the last line in the `line[]` array

`33       23.05.2012 kl. 20.00    AGF - FCM     0 - 2     12.139`

All `home_team` and `visitor_team` gets set to `AGF` and `FCM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only allocated a single `char` for home_team and visitor_team.  Use char arrays in your struct to provide space for a string:

```
#define MAX_NAME_BYTES(32) /* include space for nul terminator */
struct match {
    int round;
    int day, month, year;
    int hour, minutes;
    char home_team[MAX_NAME_BYTES];
    char visitor_team[MAX_NAME_BYTES];
    int home_score;
    int visitor_score;
    int number_of_spectators;
};
```

then use `strcpy` to copy the results into the struct:

```
strcpy(matches[i].home_team, home);
strcpy(matches[i].visitor_team, visitor);
```

Alternatively, use char pointers in your struct (as you now do in your edited question) and allocate them using `strdup`:

```
matches[i].home_team = strdup(home);
matches[i].visitor_team = strdup(visitor);
```

Note that you'll need free these strings when you discard the struct:

```
free(matches[i].home_team);
free(matches[i].visitor_team);
```

Comment: or he could make a char pointer so the strings can be of variable size. However, this would imply that the user is also responsible for allocating and deallocating the strings.

Comment: Sry! I was editing the file while posting the question. I did: char *home_team and char *visitor_team. Corrected it above

Comment: @Razcou I've updated my answer to cover this case now.  See the Alternatively... section at the end

Comment: okay, then you need to allocate space for every string in every struct. like this: `home_team = malloc(sizeof(char)*32);` for a string of 31 characters including the zero terminator.

Comment: @Evert +1, true.  This turned out to be the answer to the OP's edited question :)

Comment: Of course. `home` is just the pointer. Thanks for the quick answer!